# Pixellena Light API does not return optimized image

Tags: api, image-processing, image-optimization

Running the Light API of [Pixellena](http://pixellena.com/) I get a message similar to `Not possible to create a webp that has a smaller size and also preserves quality of the original file`, and my call does not return an image. How can I fix this so that I get the resulting optimized image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good question! It is explained on the [Pixellena FAQ](https://demo.pixellena.com/faq/) page, but actually it does not give any solution there. There is a solution though. You can use the [Lux API](https://pixellena.com/docs/lux-api/) instead, and set the `max_overhead` parameter to get an optimized image. With this parameter set you can get an optimized image bigger than the original image times the value of this parameter, as mentioned on their doc. e.g `'original image size: 10KB, max_overhead: 10, you can get an optimized image till 100KB'`. Of course it can be smaller than 100KB. In fact the API will find the smaller one possible.
​
See below how you should set the `adjustments` for that:
​

```
{
    "encoder": {
        "max_overhead": 10
    }
}
```

​
Please give it a try. Hope that it can help you.

Comment: Ok thanks, so this `max_overhead` is fixed then in the Light API or?

Comment: Hmm good question again. I just read a bit the [light API](https://pixellena.com/docs/light-api/) and in fact you can use the `max_overhead` there as well. It defaults to `0.99`, but you can send the `max_overhead` on the `light API` request data as well. I need to test that though.

Comment: I can confirm that it works with the light API, passing the max_overhead on the request data to the API request. I just tested it.